# How to get the client id of a textbox which is inside a gridview from Javascript

Tags: javascript, gridview, textbox, dom-events

I've been having this problem my whole day and I have seen almost every post on every forum/page there is and I have not found the solution to my problem. I will try to be as brief and precise as possible in my explanation.

What I want is simple, I want to dynamically copy entered numbers in `txtBox1` into `txtBox2`. Both of these txtBoxes are inside a Table which is inside a `TemplateField` which is inside a `GridView`. The `txtBox1` calls a JavaScript `numericOnly` function using the `onkeydown` event. When the user inputs a number the `numericOnly` function fires and just before the return true clause I call another JavaScript function which its supposed to do the dynamic copy from numbers entered in `txtBox1` into `txtBox2`.

The problem here is that whenever I try to use

```
document.getElementById('<%= txtDeathPremiumDifference.ClientID %>');
```

the page throws this error:

> "The name txtDeathPremiumDifference does not exist in the current context"

I must insist, I have tried EVERYTHING I've fount on internet even this:

```
document.getElementById(''<%# ((GridViewRow)Container')
        .FindControl("txtDeathPremiumDifference").ClientID %>'')
        .value="Hi";
```

but nothing has worked.

Bottom line I need to be able to access the value of my textboxes so I can modify whatever they are holding.

This is the `"txtBox1"` its not actually called like that but you get the idea:

```
TextBox ID="txtDeathBankPremium" runat="server" CssClass="TexboxInput"
     MaxLength="17" Width="122px" onkeydown="return isNumericKey(event);"
```

and here's the JS functions:

```
function isNumericKey(e)
        {
            var charInp = window.event.keyCode; 
            if (charInp > 31 && (charInp < 48 || charInp > 57)) 
            {
                return false;
            }
            ComputePremiumDifference(charInp);
            return true;
        }
        
        function ComputePremiumDifference(input) {
            document.getElementById('<%= txtDeathPremiumDifference.ClientID %>')
                    .value="Hi";
        }
```

Comment: why are you using server side code to output the id? Does your server-side script chang the textbox id? or is the id fixed? If you answer this then I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use "<%= txtDeathPremiumDifference.UniqueID %>" in your js function.
Hope it will work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It did not work though, same error: CS0103: The name 'txtDeathPremiumDifference' does not exist in the current context

Comment: I see. It's really weird if runnat="server" & ID are both correct.